# Hybrid graphic card management in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: hybrid-graphics

I need to know how to manage a hybrid dual graphic card on my laptop. Here's the config:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Robson CE [AMD Radeon HD 6300 Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: **driver=radeon latency=0**
       resources: irq:45 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:e0600000-e061ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:e0620000-e063ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: **driver=i915 latency=0**
       resources: irq:43 memory:e0000000-e03fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```